# State propagation during bactracking in Prolog

Tags: prolog, logic-programming, sicstus-prolog

Let's assume, that I have a simple program in Prolog, which is searching through a certain state space:

```
search(State, State) :-
    is_solution(State).

search(State, Solution) :-
    generate(State, NewState),
    search(NewState, Solution).
```

And I know that:

- `generate(State, NewState)` is producing at least one `NewState` for any given `State`
- the whole states space is finite

I want to modify the `search` predicate to ensure that it always manages to check in a finite time. So I write something like:

```
search(State, Solution) :-
    empty_memory(EmptyMem),
    add(State, EmptyMem, Memory),
    search(State, Memory, Solution).

search(State, _, State) :-
    is_solution(State).

search(State, Memory, Solution) :-
    generate(State, NewState),
    \+ exist(NewState, Memory),
    add(NewState, Memory, NewMemory),
    search(NewState, NewMemory, Solution).
```

which is working, but it's losing computed states during backtracking, so now I have a search tree with maximum height of space size.

Is it any way to propagate a state during the backtracking without losing any computed information? I want to have a whole search tree with O(space_size) nodes. Is it possible?

**EDIT:**
It seems that I should use `assert/[1,2]` in order to dynamically create new clauses which will serve as a global memory.

Answer (score 1):

In SICStus Prolog, you can use the blackboard to store information across backtracks: see [Blackboard Primitives](https://www.sics.se/sicstus/docs/3.12.8/html/sicstus/Blackboard-Primitives.html#Blackboard-Primitives) in the manual. Use `bb_put(Key, Value)` to store something on the blackboard, and `bb_get(Key, Value)` to retrieve it. Note that the bloackboard is defined per module.

Answer (score 1):

The most clean solution will likely be to use a Prolog compiler that supports tabling like B-Prolog, Ciao, XSB, or YAP. In this case, you would simply declare the generate/2 predicate as tabled.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `assert`, why not generate all possible states with `findall(N, generate(S,N),ALL)`. This will eliminate the need for backtracking and will explicate the search space tree, which then could be preorder-traversed while passing along the visited-so-far states as additional argument.

Comment: Hm. I forgot to specify it, but I also need to track a whole path from base state to the solution, which is slightly easier while performing DFS. Findall makes things harder, but on the other hand it much more declarative than `assert`.

Comment: I thought `findall` makes things easier. You call it, remove the already visited states, push the result on a stack (additional argument you maintain) and naturally traverse the resulting explicated tree while recording the path to each solution.